# add after content don't work

Tags: filters, content

I am using this code to put some functions after content, but this one don't work. It appear before the content and not after.

```
function add_wb_posts_pagination ($content) {
        $content .= wb_posts_pagination();
        return $content;

}
add_filter('the_content',  'add_wb_posts_pagination' );
```

is the same code i use to add others functions, but this don't work...

what can be the problem?

Comment: What theme are you customising?

Comment: what is `wb_posts_pagination()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wb_posts_pagination()` seems to be a custom function that sends its output directly to the browser with `echo` or `print`.

Use a function that returns a **string** and does not create output to add that string to `$content`.

The printed output doesn’t wait, it goes into the page the moment you call that function.